# site_url on Codeigniter doesn't work when hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I have a website, made with CodeIgniter framework. Before deploying it to external hosting everything was fine.

But, when I put my project online, I started seeing a problem. When I click on a button for move-page, I get 404 OR Page Not Found error. And I cannot reproduce it on localhost.

Here how i call my page :

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('pendaftaran/daftar'); ?>">
```

- "pendaftaran" is controller class
- "daftar" is method ro running view_pendaftaran

Comment: What is your base URL?

Comment: my base_url is URL from web hosting. @Nawin

Comment: Did you name files  and class correct Pendaftaran.php and `class Pendaftaran extends CI_Controller {}` where the first letter upper case only. Also make sure you have set your base url something liek `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: It could you need a htaccess also suited for your domain

Comment: Are you getting correct link in the url and what is it?What is the OS in local computer and and live server? Do not tell its not working. It must work unless you make any mistake.